# Keep getting undefined when i add item with redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, render, dispatch

need some serious help here. I am currently using a class component to add my items to cart but it looks like i keep getting undefined, can someone point me in the right direction please?

Homepage :

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  cartItems: state.cart.cartItems
});


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    addToCartHandler: item => {
      dispatch(addToCart(item))
    }
  }
}



renderRow =({item}) =>{
    console.log(this.state.cartItems)
    return(
      <TouchableHighlight >
      <View style ={styles.card}>
      <Image source={{uri:item.image}} style={styles.image} />
        
        <Icon name="add" size ={20} style= {styles.addToCartBtn} onPress ={() => this.props.addToCartHandler(item)} />
      
       </TouchableHighlight>
    )
  }
```

reducers

```
import { ADD_TO_CART } from '../constants'

const initialState = {
    cartItems: [],
 
    totalPrice :0
}

//add item

    export const cart = (state = initialState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case ADD_TO_CART:
                console.log("reducer",action)
                var {item} =action.payload;
                var newState =Object.assign({},{...state});
    
           
            for (var i = 0; i < state.cartItems.length; i++) {
           
          newState.cartItems = newState.cartItems.concat(item);
          console.log(newState)
          return newState
          
    
          }
    
    
    
            default:
                return state
        }

}
```

action

```
import {ADD_TO_CART} from '../constants'
import {REMOVE_FROM_CART} from '../constants'


 export const addToCart =(item) =>{
   // console.log(item)
    return{
        type: ADD_TO_CART,
        payload : item,
    };
}
```

Dont think anything is wrong with my action or rootreducers. I am not sure why i keep getting undefined whenever i add to cart when i can console.log the item

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating the new state correctly, I think the following will work:

```
case ADD_TO_CART:
  console.log('reducer', action);
  var item = action.payload;
  return {
    ...state,
    cartItems:state.cartItems.concat(item)
  }
```

[Here](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) is some useful information on how to create a new state.